# Problemas em configurar rota no rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

sou novo como programador ruby on rails.

Eu executei no console do windows **rails generate controller hello** depois criei a pagina na pasta View um arquivo index.html.erb, em seguida configurei a rota no arquivo routes.erb criando a seguinte linha;

**get  'hello/index'**

E digitei a URL **localhost:3000/hello/index** gerou esse erro;[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me dizer o que está havendo de erro?

porque não consigo subir minha pagina se configurei a rota da forma correta?

Conseguir resolver o problema através dessa postagem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221961/application-html-erb-where-line-6-raised-typeerror-ruby-on-rails

no arquivo **views/layouts/aplication.html.erb** eu troquei isso;

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

por isso;

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Por gentileza gostaria somente saber porque resolveu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para compilar os assets de CoffeeScript e JavaScript, o Rails requer o JavaScript Runtime instalado em seu computador, caso não possua, ele retorna esse erro durante a compilação dos assets. Normalmente esse erro não ocorre com usuários de Linux e Mac, pois o Runtime já vem instalado.

Não é uma boa prática você setar para `default`, pois você irá perder a compatibilidade com os estilos do application.css. Uma solução é instalar o NodeJs e reiniciar o server, ou então instalar a gem `gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'` e em seguida rodar `bundle update coffee-script-source`

Comment: eu instalei a versão mais recente de Javascript e não deu certo, depois instalei o NodeJs e também não funcionou, mais alguma sugestão? por favor

Comment: Tente utilizar alguma dessas soluções: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362458/error-when-running-rails-app-execjsruntimeerror